# Adding a counter in python

Tags: python, counter

```
counter=0

import random

myNum = random.choice(('j', 'Nk', 'p', 'qr', 'stu'))

print(myNum)

if myNum != 'j':

    counter+=1

print(counter)
```

How do I make it so that the counter keeps counting the number of times that 'j' does not appear and doesn't reset after 'j' appears?

Comment: `counter+1` does nothing useful... `counter+=1` is more like it.

Comment: sorry, How do I make the counter work? And am I doing the != thing right?

Comment: I wanted to keep a separate counter to count the amount of times that 'j' DOES NOT appear.

Comment: @swmr007: but you're not repeating the experiment at all??

Comment: Can someone help me with that?

Comment: I am new to this so can you guys send me a sample of how you all would keep a separate counter

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add information about exactly what it is you want to know. Just putting a few comments down here isn't good enough for SO.

Comment: @swmr007: please in the future, first take a look at your question before you post it. Does it look ok (formatting)? Can a person answer my question (enough information)? Can they *reproduce* the problem I am facing.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: sorry, how would you all go about solving my issue?

Comment: I voted to close. Wish someone would just delete this question.

Comment: This question should describe what the program is supposed to do with more clarity... And write a more descriptive title. The current title is attracting a lot of clicks and probably annoying a lot of visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Responding to your EDIT:

```
counter=0
import random
for i in range(0,100): #How many times you want to repeat
    myNum = random.choice(('j', 'Nk', 'p', 'qr', 'stu'))
    print(myNum)
    if myNum != 'j':
        counter+=1
print(counter)
```

or

```
counter=0
import random
while 1: #repeats forever
    myNum = random.choice(('j', 'Nk', 'p', 'qr', 'stu'))
    print(myNum)
    if myNum != 'j':
        counter+=1
print(counter)
```

Comment: It's too bad when the person answering the question also has to ask it - on behalf of the OP. The OP needs to go away and do a Python course. Encouraging this sort of spam on the site is not a good idea, even for the OP. This question needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Doning this

```
counter+1
```

is getting the value of counter, add one to it and thorwing the result in the  bin of garbage, if you dont assign that result to anything it just will get lost...  You meant for sure `counter+=1`

Comment: Thankyou but how do i make sure that the counter stays and keep counting the amount of times that 'j' does not appear, and not reset?